# Java gives 00:00:00 time when gathering dateTime from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, time, jodatime

I'm trying to gather a certain time from my SQL database, and then comparing it to the current date to check wether the user is currently banned.

It displays the date that it gathers from the db correctly, but the time is just 00:00:00 every time.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public static boolean checkBan(String playerName, String type) {
    Format formatter;
    Date date = new Date();
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        createConnection();
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE username = '"
                + playerName + "'";
        ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while (results.next()) {
            java.sql.Date mysqlDate = results.getDate(type);
            if (mysqlDate == null || formatter.format(date) == null) {
                return false;
            } else {
                java.util.Date dateConverter = new java.util.Date(
                        mysqlDate.getTime());
                DateTime now = new DateTime(formatter.format(date));
                DateTime end = new DateTime(formatter.format(dateConverter));
                int mins = Minutes.minutesBetween(now, end).getMinutes();
                System.out.println("Start time: " + now);
                System.out.println("End time: " + end);
                System.out.println("Difference in minutes:" + mins);
                if (mins <= 0) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        destroyCon();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        destroyCon();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

The output it gives me is:

Start time: 2012-07-16T20:26:50.000Z

End time: 2012-07-16T00:00:00.000Z

Difference in minutes:-1226

But the end time that is stored in the SQL database is: 2012-07-16 21:13:31

Some other info:
I'm using Joda-time and the sql database and the java server is ran on the same server.
Please tell me if you need more information.

Comment: at Stackoverflow we don't rename our questions to Solved, we mark an answer as accepted

Answer (score 4):

`java.sql.Date` is defined to be a time-less date.  When you use that type, it will chop the time information out of the date regardless of what is in the database.  If you want both Date and Time information, you want to use `getTimestamp()` on the ResultSet, not `getDate()`.

Comment: Oh okay didn't realise that. I will try using getTimeStamp instead. Thanks :)

Comment: Okay, the problem was resolved when I used timestamp instead. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

As told in API documentation [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) does not have time component (all time related field are set to 0). It matches to SQL date.

Use [java.sql.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

never used mysql with java,
but if `java.sql.Date mysqlDate` is a mysql `DATE`, insted of a `DATETIME`,
then that could be the problem

**update**
in [oracle doc: java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)

"If the given ... value contains time information, the driver will set the time components ... to zero GMT."

Comment: I am currently using DATETIME in the SQL database.

Comment: if you use DATETIME in mysql, and then convert it to DATE in Java, you lose the time info

Comment: Yes, I just realised that. And now I'm strugling to getting it to convert it to TimeStamp instead of date, but I'm sure I'll get the hang of it after a little try and fail :P